# How to stop parent control taking touch event when it contains a nested button

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, touch

so I have my control which I would like to expand on touch and show my button which is nested within the data template of the control. I would then like the button to be pressable but would also like the control to collapse if touched anywhere apart from the button

**Initialise Control**

```
MyControl mc = new MyControl();
mc.TouchDown += mc_TouchDown;
mc.TouchUp += mc_TouchUp;
```

**Event handlers**

```
    void mc_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var mc = (MyControl)sender;
        mc.CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
    }

    void mc_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var mc = (MyControl)sender;
        if (mc != null && e.TouchDevice.Captured == mc)
        {
            //Expand and show button / Collapse and hide button
            mc.ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);
        }
    }
```

Now the button is in the data template of `MyControl` and is hooked up to a command and when i touch the button to run the command `MyControl` touch events are being fired and the button tap gets ignored.

How do I make it so that the touch events on `MyControl` work but when the button is shown and touched the button touch event takes priority over the `MyControl` event?

Comment: Have you tried handling `PreviewTouchDown` and `PreviewTouchUp` instead of `TouchDown` and `TouchUp`?

Comment: @StevenRands Just tried it but still the same behavior. From my understanding using Preview instead would just mean that the touch event is fired quicker?

Comment: That's not really the difference between a _tunneling_ and a _bubbling_ event. Anyway, I suspect your problem is something to do with the touch capturing. Given the behaviour that you're describing for your custom control, would an `Expander` control be a better fit?

Comment: @StevenRands to give some more info to the question the control is a PushPin on a map from a third party lib, that I have expanded to respond to touch events that dynamically set the datatemplate giving the appearance of an expanding / Collapsing control. But this means that any controls in the data template are then not responding to touch events

Comment: Maybe try expanding/collapsing solely on the `TouchDown` event? Remove the touch capture stuff and the `TouchUp` event handler altogether and see if you still have the same problem?

Comment: @StevenRands I've tried removing the capture stuff but still the same problem sadly

Comment: OK. Sorry, I'm out of ideas on this one.

Comment: Unless you are handling the bubbling up of the event when you touch the button your event handler TouchUp event handler looks like it will always get called. If I were you before doing anything with commands on the inner button I will put regular event handlers and see the order in which things get called. And what happens when you mark the event as handled within the inner button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was using Command for my button but I changed this to use the `TouchDown` event instead and had

```
    private void addToDiary_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        //do my thing
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

and this meant the button was executed and the event didn't bubble up to `MyControl`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `e.Handled = true` for `TouchEventArgs` to prevent a bubbling of event.